# Equations to return the result of series calculation

Tags: worksheet-function

I'm working on a spreadsheet to figure out the capabilities of an electric-drive boat.  The proposed boat has batteries, solar panels, and a generator that can be used if no other energy is available.  I want to figure out the maximum time said boat can rest at anchor without refueling the generator, and how far the boat can travel.  The solar part throws me off, because it adds an over-time factor into the equation.  It seems like I could leverage `PV()` or `FV()` to get the answer, but I suspect that MS Excel or Google Sheets have more elegant functions built in that I don't understand how to use.

How do I write the functions for **Time at Anchor** and **Range** in the table below?

| Measure | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Motor Consumption Underway (kWh/km) 11 kph | 0.84 |
| Battery Capacity (kWh) | 72 |
| Generator Capacity (kWh) | 466 |
| **Total Energy (kWh)** | **538** |
| House Power Consumption (kWh/h) | 2.0 |
| Solar Power Per Day (kWh/24h) | 8.0 |
| Time at Anchor (h) | `???` |
| Range (km) | `???` |

Presume that the generator can keep up with the total load of the motor and the house power.

---

**EDIT**: Per the request below, here's how I think it should go (circular reference and all):

```
AtAnchorNoSolarHours = TotalEnergyNoSolar/HousePowerConsumption
DaysAtAnchorNoSolar = AtAnchorNoSolarHours/24
SolarEnergy = DaysAtAnchorNoSolar * SolarPowerPerDay
TimeAtAnchor = (TotalEnergyNoSolar + SolarEnergy)/HousePowerConsumption
```

Similarly, range:

```
RangeNoSolar = TotalEnergy / MotorConsumptionUnderway
HoursUnderway = TotalEnergy / MotorConsumptionUnderway *** Not sure here ***
DaysUnderway = HoursUnderway/24
SolarEnergy = DaysUnderway * SolarEnergyPerDay
Range = RangeNoSolar + (SolarEnergy * MotorConsumptionUnderway)
```

Comment: What are PV and FV?

Comment: @MátéJuhász, `pv()` solves for the "present value of an annuity investment" and `fv()` for the "future value of an annuity investment".  They're interest rate functions, and I was thinking that one or the other might be used in this calculation if you presumed that the solar energy input was akin to the interest rate on your investment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take two approaches here:

### 1. Math

By solving some simple equations you can easily calculate your results

**Time at anchor:**

- `'TotalE + Solar * x / 24 = HouseP *x`
- `x = TotalE / (HouseP - Solar / 24)`
- which gives you the result: 322.8

**Range:**

- `TotalE + Solar * s / v / 24 = MotorC * s`
- `'s = TotalE / (MotorC - Solar / v / 24)`
- result: 664.4461

### 2. Solver:

For more complex models you can use [Solver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040):

Here you need to set up support cells where you calculate energy balance (total Energy (available + generated) - energy consumed):

- balance for time (C10): `=B7+B9*B10/24-B8*B10`
- balance for range (C11): `=B7+B9*B11/B12/24-B4*B11`

Running solver for time:

- start solver
- set objective: C10
- To: `value of 0`
- By Changing variable cells: B10
- click solve
  [image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: This is precisely the sort of thing I was looking for.

Comment: Hang on, in your Math section, what is `v` meant to represent?

Comment: That's the speed. I used 11 km/h.

Answer (score 3):

You have the data that assumes no solar:

```
AtAnchorNoSolarHours = TotalEnergyNoSolar/HousePowerConsumption
DaysAtAnchorNoSolar = AtAnchorNoSolarHours/24
```

Solar changes the above by adding energy at a rate approximated as 8kWh/24h (presumably you don't actually get solar energy at night or when cloudy, so you're really looking for how this changes days at anchor).

I suggest you add one calculated value you don't have:

```
HousePowerConsumptionPerDay = HousePowerConsumption * 24h
```

Then you're looking for the place where the total amount of energy generated at time D (days at anchor) and the total amount of energy used at time D are the same.  This is an equation like:

```
TotalEnergyNoSolar + (Days * SolarPowerPerDay) = (HousePowerConsumptionPerDay * Days)
```

You then solve this for Days:

```
TotalEnergyNoSolar = (HousePowerConsumptionPerDay * Days) - (Days * SolarPowerPerDay)
```

Split out the Days part on the right side:

```
TotalEnergyNoSolar = (HousePowerConsumptionPerDay - SolarPowerPerDay) * Days
```

And then divide to get an equation for number of days until they match:

```
TotalEnergyNoSolar / (HousePowerConsumptionPerDay - SolarPowerPerDay) = Days
```

Keep in mind that your solar generation is going to be highly variable, so you should be conservative on your calculated Days.

For the range, your first pseudocode line there is wrong unless your units are mis-specified in the table.  I think it should be (to get kilometers):

```
RangeNoSolar = TotalEnergy / MotorConsumptionUnderway
```

You also don't actually have any information on the speed of the boat underway, so you can't get the amount of time involved (you just have how much energy to travel a given distance).  With an appropriate average speed (averaged over a full 24 hour day), you can get:

```
TravelHoursNoSolar = RangeNoSolar / SpeedInKmPerHour
```

Then you're pretty much in the same boat (it's a joke!) as the first formula:

Energy used by motor in N days == Energy stored + solar energy in N days.

Solve for N.

```
MotorConsumptionUnderway (kWh/km) * SpeedInKmPerHour (km/h) * 24hours/Day * Days = TotalEnergyNoSolar + (Days * SolarPowerPerDay)
```

This breaks out to:

```
TotalEnergyNoSolar = ( MotorConsumptionUnderway * SpeedInKmPerHour * 24 * Days ) - (Days * SolarPowerPerDay)
```

Then pull days out:

```
TotalEnergyNoSolar = Days * ( MotorConsumptionUnderway * SpeedInKmPerHour * 24 ) - SolarPowerPerDay
```

And finally divide for Days:

```
DaysRange = TotalEnergyNoSolar / (( MotorConsumptionUnderway * SpeedInKmPerHour * 24 ) - SolarPowerPerDay)
```

You can get range distance by multiplying DaysRange by average speed per day.

Also to note, the range is assuming you don't power anything other than the motor.  If that isn't true, you need to add daily additional power consumption to the daily motor power consumption.

Comment: I neglected to put the speed underway in the table above.  Corrected to 11 kph.

Comment: Regarding range, you're correct: it should be `RangeNoSolar = TotalEnergy / MotorConsumptionUnderway`.  Fixing...